# Withdrawing a Schengen visa (business class) application

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, cancellations, applications

I recently applied for a business Schengen visa to Switzerland (from India). However my visa approval is delayed and the purpose of the trip, which was to attend some crucial meetings, is not applicable any more. My client and I do not feel it is necessary to make the trip anymore and would like to withdraw/cancel my visa application.

Is this easy to do? Will canceling my application reflect poorly on me and hamper my future chances of traveling to the EU region or to Switzerland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Canceling the application should be fine.**  Getting rejected is a problem, but a cancellation makes no difference either way.

That said, since they're unlikely to refund you the application cost, I would just go ahead and get the visa.  You never know when the next business trip will come along, and having one approved visa will make getting the next one easier, even if you never use it!

Comment: Just to add, make sure you utilize the visa, if/when you get it, as unused C Class visas arw frowned upon in future applications.

Comment: @Davinder Got source? Most regulars here would disagree.

Comment: @jpatokal No, but was googling the same thing in Nov-2015, about an unused C type Schengen tourist visa issued by Spain embassy, and the staff at phone advised that if plans are changed (i.e. cancelled), inform embassy to get the visa cancelled. No source, thats why just a comment.